# Jquery add and remove text on hover but don't remove on click

Tags: jquery, text, hover, click, string

I'm using this code to show some text when I hover over #one. But when I 'hover out' or mouseleave, I want the text to disappear. That works fine. The problem arises when I CLICK on #one, then I want that text to stay (but it won't because the .empty function on the hover won't allow. Any ideas?

```
<div class="info"><p></p></div>



$('#one').hover(function() {
        $('.info p').text('Some Text');
    },
        function() {
         $('.info p').empty();

    });

  $('#one').click(function()
        $('.info p').text('Some Text');

    });
```

Comment: You could unbind the hover when you click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on `#one`, add a class to `.info` like `.active`, and change the `mouseout` section of `hover` to not trigger when `info` is `.active`

```
$('#one').click(function()
    $('.info p').addClass('active').text('Some Text');
});

$('#one').hover(function() {
    $('.info p').text('Some Text');
},
    function() {
     if (!$('.info p').hasClass('active')) {
         $('.info p').empty();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use mouseleave and mouseenter to bind the events, this way you can use $('#one').unbind('mouseleave') in the click handler, in order to prevent the text from disappearing when you mouse out. Then rebind the mouseleave handler on re-enter. Kinda tricky.

Comment: I've added another button that takes me back to the original state, using your bind/unbind method but the bind isn't working! So after I click and unbind the hover, I can't bind it again? Can you have a look at this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/Alga/9LGA9/